# ansible regex replace all matching string1, exclude string2

Tags: python, regex, ansible

I'd like to replace all instances of `dogs` with `cats`, except for those where the line has `does not play with mice`.

My file contents looks like:

```
dogs:plays with mice
dogs:plays with mice
dogs:does not play with mice
dogs:plays with mice
dogs:plays with mice
dogs:does not play with mice
dogs:plays with mice
```

Below are the important bits to my ansible-playbook, to try achieve the desired result:

```
  vars:
    file_to_update: /tmp/cats_dogs_file.txt
    exclude: "does not play with mice"
    from_name: "dogs"
    to_name: "cats"

  tasks:    

  - name: updates dogs to cats - excluding the necessary
    replace:
      path: "{{ file_to_update }}"
      regexp: "^{{ from_name }}(?! {{ exclude }})"
      replace: "{{ to_name }}"
    register: file_update_status
```

I expect the contents of the file to be changed as per the below:

```
cats:plays with mice
cats:plays with mice
dogs:does not play with mice
cats:plays with mice
cats:plays with mice
dogs:does not play with mice
cats:plays with mice
```

Instead I currently get all `dogs` changed to `cats`.

The exclude is not being adhered to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

The first option below is what you need. The second option is the original answer updated in the third option.

1. Correct Python regex, started with the negative lookahead assertion, is

```yaml
        regexp: '^(?!.*{{ exclude }}){{ from_name }}(.*)$'
        replace: '{{ to_name }}\1'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    file_to_update: /tmp/cats_dogs_file.txt
    exclude: does not play with mice
    from_name: dogs
    to_name: cats
    
  tasks:

    - replace:
        path: "{{ file_to_update }}"
        regexp: '^(?!.*{{ exclude }}){{ from_name }}(.*)$'
        replace: '{{ to_name }}\1'
```

gives (abridged, running with --check --diff options)

```yaml
--- before: /tmp/cats_dogs_file.txt
+++ after: /tmp/cats_dogs_file.txt
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
-dogs:plays with mice
-dogs:plays with mice
+cats:plays with mice
+cats:plays with mice
 dogs:does not play with mice
-dogs:plays with mice
-dogs:plays with mice
+cats:plays with mice
+cats:plays with mice
 dogs:does not play with mice
-dogs:plays with mice
+cats:plays with mice
```

---

2. A simple solution for a local file on the controller would be to loop over the lines and conditionally exclude the lines that shall not be replaced.

---

The task below

```yaml
    tasks:
      - replace:
          path: "{{ file_to_update }}"
          regexp: "{{ item }}"
          replace: "{{ item | regex_replace(from_name, to_name) }}"
        with_lines: "cat {{ file_to_update }}"
        when: exclude not in item
```

gives (abridged):

```yaml
TASK [replace] 
**************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=dogs:plays with mice)
ok: [localhost] => (item=dogs:plays with mice)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=dogs:does not play with mice) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=dogs:plays with mice)
ok: [localhost] => (item=dogs:plays with mice)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=dogs:does not play with mice) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=dogs:plays with mice)
```

---

3. The second option is repeating the replacement of the same lines. The task below is more efficient. It iterates selected unique lines only. This option is not limited to the local files on the controller.

---

Read the file

```yaml
    - command: "cat {{ file_to_update }}"
      register: out
      changed_when: false
```

and select unique lines

```yaml
    lines: "{{ out.stdout_lines |
               unique |
               reject('search', exclude) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  lines:
  - dogs:plays with mice
```

The task below replaces all matches in a single iteration

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: "{{ file_to_update }}"
        regexp: "{{ item }}"
        replace: "{{ item | regex_replace(from_name, to_name) }}"
      loop: "{{ lines }}"
```

---

Result. The result of all options is the edited file below

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/cats_dogs_file.txt
cats:plays with mice
cats:plays with mice
dogs:does not play with mice
cats:plays with mice
cats:plays with mice
dogs:does not play with mice
cats:plays with mice
```

Comment: Thanks @VladimirBotka, your solution worked! :-)
I just had to add in a [slurp task](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22816), to get the contents of the file, as the file resided remotely.

Comment: I updated the remote options and fixed the regex negative lookahead assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, here we could write an expression and find the parts of your desired output and replace them. Maybe something similar to:

```
(.+):(plays? with)\s(.+)
```

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /(.+):(plays? with)\s(.+)/gm;
const str = `dogs:plays with mice
dogs:plays with mice
dogs:does not play with mice
dogs:plays with mice
dogs:plays with mice
dogs:does not play with mice
dogs:plays with mice

cats:plays with mice
cats:plays with mice
dogs:does not play with mice
cats:plays with mice
cats:plays with mice
dogs:does not play with mice
cats:plays with mice`;
const subst = `cats:$2 $3`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### Python Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(.+):(plays? with)\s(.+)"

test_str = ("dogs:plays with mice\n"
    "dogs:plays with mice\n"
    "dogs:does not play with mice\n"
    "dogs:plays with mice\n"
    "dogs:plays with mice\n"
    "dogs:does not play with mice\n"
    "dogs:plays with mice\n\n"
    "cats:plays with mice\n"
    "cats:plays with mice\n"
    "dogs:does not play with mice\n"
    "cats:plays with mice\n"
    "cats:plays with mice\n"
    "dogs:does not play with mice\n"
    "cats:plays with mice")

subst = "cats:\\2 \\3"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ofYIX4/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]